# schema: does not match the regex pattern

Tags: snowplow

We use an **unstruct_event** but it always results in this failure. I do not understand what goes wrong here. What schema field is going wrong here, the schema field of the **unstruct_event** or the schema field of the **data** object within the **unstruct_event**? It would be extremely valuable to have the actual failing value in the error message here...

```
"failure": {
  "timestamp": "2021-01-20T08:03:51.128Z",
  "messages": [
    {
      "schemaKey": "iglu:com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow/unstruct_event/jsonschema/1-0-0",
      "error": {
        "error": "ValidationError",
        "dataReports": [
          {
            "message": "$.schema: does not match the regex pattern ^iglu:[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+$",
            "path": "$.schema",
            "keyword": "pattern",
            "targets": [
              "^iglu:[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+$"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the unstruct_event field from the payload:

```
    "unstruct_event": "{\"schema\":\"iglu:com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow/unstruct_event/jsonschema/1-0-0\",\"data\":{\"schema\":\"https://thijsbucket-dev.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/schemas/com.thijslearning/thijs-event/jsonschema/1-0-1.json\",\"data\":{\"event\":\"clicks\",\"action\":\"Feed rename item\",\"label\":\"2 Metadata\",\"CD_thijs_id\":\"5424\",\"CD_role\":\"thijser\",\"CD_method_name\":\"0 Thijs Manual MR\",\"CD_language\":\"en\",\"CD_window_size\":\"1024x768\",\"CD_demo_yn\":false}}}",
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was that I added `.json` to the schema value in the event and it should be without `.json` so ending with `1-0-1` in the schema value as well is in the schema repository (S3 in my case).

Comment: Great that you could figure this out!